# Store all locations between source and destination in a table(database)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3

I want to parse all the locations between source and destination from the google map which is shown below:
    
     
     
     
    Google Maps API v3 Directions Example

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 

 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom:7,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
 directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

 var request = {
   origin: 'Kolkata', 
   destination: 'Patna',
   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
 };

//echo 'directionsService.route()';

 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
   }
 });
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I want something like [http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=%22+kolkata+%22&destination=%22+patna+%22&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=%22%20kolkata%20%22&destination=%22%20patna%20%22&sensor=false)

So that I can parse the locations and store in a table in my database. Please help to find a way to do this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you would need to (in what ever language you are using) get the XML into an array or datatable (or equivalent) then insert those row by row into the database.

PHP: http://gaarf.info/2009/08/13/xml-string-to-php-array/

VB.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekw4dh3f(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: But I have to give a separate link to :[link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=%22+kolkata+%22&destination=%22+patna+%22&sensor=false) for parsing the places. I want to retrieve the XML from map i m using and don't want to give any separate link